# How to install third-party library with automatic dependencies resolving and building the project

Tags: javascript, bower, share-button

I install a fork of a third-party library (https://github.com/VyacheslavAlexeev/share-button) via the following command:

```
bower install git://github.com/VyacheslavAlexeev/share-button.git#6770b9469a511dba62250eddace08c5916a67570
```

but it just downloads all files from repository without installing all dependencies and building the project via gulp. Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: You may want to use bower install [some_component] --save-dev. This options will persist the component to your bower.json file.

Comment: No, the OP's asking how to install the dependencies specified in the rep's package.json file after it's been downloaded.

Comment: @Jodevan It'll just save this third-party library to the `devDependencies` section instead of `dependencies` section. How is it supposed to help me?

Comment: Pretty sure @FrozenHeart, that when I did this (I was using Grunt) I had to download and then install the dependencies as part of the same task. I don't think it does it automatically.

Comment: @FrozenHeart Try using the npm install: `npm install share-button@^1.0.2`.

Comment: @Andy What's the difference? `npm` can install dependencies for third-party libraries while `bower` can't?

Comment: Probably. I've not read the bower documentation.

Comment: @Andy I think that I can't use npm for such purposes because `share-button` library consists not only of JS files but CSS too, so it's not enough to just use `browserify` or smth like this